# What was the [theoretical] reward for perfect obedience to the Law of Moses?

Tags: torah

We often hear it said that faith in the Lord Jesus Christ is rewarded with eternal life in heaven.

For example, in *What Must I Do to Be Saved? (A Devotional)*, James R. Anderson wrote,<sup>1</sup>

> [John 20:31] is one more verse that clearly teaches that we gain life, meaning eternal life in heaven with Jesus, by simply believing in Him.

On the other hand, Jews (who do not believe in the Lord Jesus Christ) often say that keeping the Torah is rewarded with eternal life in Gan Eden.<sup>2</sup>

For example, *Midrash Shmot Rabba*, [Parsha 2.2](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/tanach/raba2/2.htm),<sup>3</sup>

> Whoever keeps the Torah, behold, Gan Eden is in his future, but whoever does not keep it, behold, Gehinnom [is in his future].
>
> מי שהוא שומר את התורה, הרי גן עדן לפניו, ומי שאינו משמרה, הרי גיהנם

The Torah seems to state that those who keep it will only **prolong their days in the land that they are going to possess**. For example, in Deuteronomy 4:40, it is written,

> <sup>40</sup> And you shall keep His statutes and His commandments that I command you today, so that it will be well for you and for your children after you, and so that you may prolong your days upon the land that Yahveh your God is giving you, all the days.

**Question**: is there anywhere in the Torah that states that Yahveh promises those who keep the Torah, that is, those who (theoretically) do “all the words that Yahveh had said,”<sup>4</sup> that they will receive eternal life?<sup>5</sup>

---

#### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> p. [54](https://books.google.com/books?id=9sO855hdsX4C&lpg=PP1&pg=PA54#v=onepage&q&f=true)
<sup>2</sup> The Jewish concept of גן עדן, or Paradise (from Greek παράδεισος, cf. Gen. 2:8 LXX), is analogous to heaven as the place of the righteous in the world to come. cf. 2 Cor. 12:4. According to the Jewish Encyclopedia, entry on “[Eden, Garden of](http://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/6503-gan-eden)”:

> The Talmudists and Cabalists agree that there are two gardens of Eden: one, the terrestrial, of abundant fertility and luxuriant vegetation; the other, celestial, the habitation of righteous, immortal souls. These two are known as the “lower” and “higher” Gan Eden.

<sup>3</sup> a.k.a. Midrash Exodus Rabba
<sup>4</sup> Exo. 24:3
<sup>5</sup> in the celestial Gan Eden, Paradise, etc.

#### References

Anderson, James R. [*What Must I Do to Be Saved? (A Devotional).*](https://books.google.com/books?id=9sO855hdsX4C) Collierville: Innovo, 2011.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not Jewish person but a person who has a Christian point of view….and an unorthodox view needless to say.

Keeping and doing His commandments, statutes and judgments has the promise of life attached to them.  “Do them so that you may live”.

I think it is “eternal life” that is being spoken of even though it does not explicitly say “eternal life” in the Torah.  A “prolonged life” is an eternal life in this earth that is promised by the keeping and doing of God’s commandments.

The Torah is all about this life in this earth in the here-and-now.   We shall live to possess this earth in due time (in the world or age to come) by working and keeping His commandments always.  We shall live to see all of the kingdoms of this world become His in due time (the world to come).

> *Deuteronomy 4:1 KJV (1)  Now therefore hearken, O Israel, unto the statutes and unto the judgments, which I teach you, for to do them,
>   **that ye may live, and go in and possess the land** which the LORD God of
>   your fathers giveth you.*

We show we love God by the keeping of His statutes, His judgments and His commandments….always.

> *Deuteronomy 11:1 KJV (1)  **Therefore thou shalt love the LORD thy God, and keep his charge, and his statutes, and his judgments, and his
>   commandments, alway***.

By remembering to do them always, our days shall be multiplied in this earth (“in the land”) as the days of Heaven upon the earth.  This is not about going to Heaven but living the Heaven-like life here in this earth.  Life in Heaven is eternal. His kingdom is eternal.  His dominion is eternal. In Heaven, His will is always done.

> *Deuteronomy 11:20-21 KJV (20)  And thou shalt write them upon the door posts of thine house, and upon thy gates: (21)  **That your days
>   may be multiplied, and the days of your children, in the land which
>   the LORD sware unto your fathers to give them, as the days of heaven
>   upon the earth.***
>
> *Deuteronomy 12:1 KJV (1)  **These are the statutes and judgments, which ye shall observe to do in the land, which the LORD God of thy fathers
>   giveth thee to possess it, all the days that ye live upon the earth.***

The promise of eternal life is found in the “tree of life” in the center of the Garden of Eden as indicated in Genesis 3:22 where the tree of life might have been eaten and the man would live “forever” (eternal life).   One has to go back to the Beginning to see this connection.

> *Genesis 3:22 KJV (22)  And the LORD God said, Behold, the man is become as one of us, to know good and evil: and now, lest he put forth
>   his hand, a**nd take also of the tree of life, and eat, and live for
>   ever**:*

I am thinking that the “Garden of Eden” that God put the man to “dress and keep” (or rather to “work” and keep) are the commandments of God that are to be worked and kept by man.   “Dress” = to work/serve.

> *Genesis 2:15 KJV (15)  And the LORD God took the man, and put him into the garden of Eden **to dress it and to keep it.***

God breathed His Spirit into the man so that the man would delight (Eden) in the keeping of His commandments that He placed man to work and keep.

> *Genesis 2:7-8 KJV (7)  And the LORD God formed man of the dust of the ground, and **breathed into his nostrils the breath of lif**e; and man
>   became a living soul. (8)  And the LORD God planted a garden eastward
>   in Eden; **and there he put the man whom he had forme**d.*

Without the indwelling of His Spirit, it is impossible for man to please God.  But with His Spirit, He works in us to both to will to do His good pleasure (Eden= delight/pleasure).

> *Philippians 2:13 KJV (13)  **For it is God which worketh in you both to will and to do of his good pleasure.***

Only with the indwelling of His Spirit (God breathed the Spirit of life into the man) can we delight to work and keep His commandments.   A "river" went out of Eden to water the garden as His Spirit works within us to want to do His commandments.

> *Genesis 2:10 KJV (10)  **And a river went out of Eden to water the garden;** and from thence it was parted, and became into four heads.*

Those who do not have His Spirit within them cannot please God (Eden = delight/pleasure).   They do not delight in His commandments.

> *Romans 8:8-9 KJV (8)  S**o then they that are in the flesh cannot please God. (9)  But ye are not in the flesh, but in the Spirit, if so
>   be that the Spirit of God dwell in you. Now if any man have not the
>   Spirit of Christ, he is none of his.***

The “Garden of Eden” is not a physical place but a place where we know and love God by the keeping of His commandments via His Spirit.  We continue to abide in Him and Him in us if we work and keep His commandments.  We walk with God in the “Garden of Eden”.  “Eden” means “delight, pleasure”.  Man “delights” in the Torah of the LORD and He delights in those who work and keep them.

> *Psalms 1:1-3 KJV (1)  Blessed is the man that walketh not in the counsel of the ungodly, nor standeth in the way of sinners, nor
>   sitteth in the seat of the scornful. (2)  **But his delight is in the
>   law of the LORD; and in his law doth he meditate day and night. (3) 
>   And he shall be like a tree planted by the rivers of water, that
>   bringeth forth his fruit in his season; his leaf also shall not
>   wither; and whatsoever he doeth shall prosper**.*

This is the love of God:  that we keep His commandments (God placed the man to work and keep the “Garden of Eden”).

> *1 John 5:2-3 KJV (2)  By this we know that we love the children of God, when we love God, and keep his commandments. (3)  **For this is the
>   love of God, that we keep his commandments: and his commandments are
>   not grievous**.*

Of the trees of the garden we are to freely eat of...except for one.

> *Genesis 2:16-17 KJV (16)  **And the LORD God commanded the man, saying, Of every tree of the garden thou mayest freely eat**: (17)  But of the
>   tree of the knowledge of good and evil, thou shalt not eat of it: for
>   in the day that thou eatest thereof thou shalt surely die.*

The fruit of the Spirit is love, joy, peace, etc.  Against such there is no law.  We are free to eat of every tree of the Garden.

> *Galatians 5:22-25 KJV (22)  **But the fruit of the Spirit is love, joy, peace, longsuffering, gentleness, goodness, faith, (23)  Meekness,
>   temperance: against such there is no law**. (24)  And they that are
>   Christ's have crucified the flesh with the affections and lusts. (25) 
>   **If we live in the Spirit, let us also walk in the Spiri**t.*

We reap life everlasting if we continue to sow after the Spirit.

> *Galatians 6:7-9 KJV (7)  Be not deceived; God is not mocked: for whatsoever a man soweth, that shall he also reap. (8)  For he that
>   soweth to his flesh shall of the flesh reap corruption; **but he that
>   soweth to the Spirit shall of the Spirit reap life everlasting**. (9) 
>   And let us not be weary in well doing: for in due season we shall
>   reap, if we faint not.*

We have to go back to the Beginning to see the promise of eternal life in the tree of life for those who will work and keep His commandments.

NOW In order for man to gain access to that tree of life, he must use the Spirit within to kill the deeds of the body (use the “sword” of the Spirit).  Through the Spirit do we mortify (slay) the deeds of the body so that we may live (gain access to the tree of life).

> *Romans 8:12-14 KJV (12)  Therefore, brethren, we are debtors, not to the flesh, to live after the flesh. (13)  For if ye live after the
>   flesh, ye shall die: **but if ye through the Spirit do mortify the deeds
>   of the body, ye shall live. (14)  For as many as are led by the Spirit
>   of God, they are the sons of God**.*

A flaming sword keeps the way of the tree of life.   We have to use the sword of the Spirit to slay the deeds of the body in order to enter into His rest and live.

> *Genesis 3:24 KJV (24)  So he drove out the man; and he placed at the east of the garden of Eden Cherubims, **and a flaming sword which turned
>   every way, to keep the way of the tree of life**.*

Answer (score 0):

## "Prosperity" & "Success"

***Joshua 1:8***

In the purely Biblical sense of your question, the "***Law of Moses***" contains ***Genesis through Deuteronomy***. The very next book is ***Joshua***, where the first chapter is a kind of "introduction" or perhaps "preamble" to the ***Law of Moses***. In Joshua 1, verse 8 explains the four step consequence of obedience:

> **Joshua 1:8** This book of the law shall not depart from your mouth, but you shall meditate on it day and night, so that you may be careful to do according to all that is written in it; for then you will make your way prosperous, and then you will have success. (**NASB**)

"Obedience" is the second step, "prosperity" and "success", in turn, following. That is the most direct, "Biblical" answer to your question since Joshua 1 states that it addresses "this book of the law".

As for the concept of "perfect" obedience, there is no such distinction between "perfect" and "imperfect" obedience in the Old Testament. Speaking in purely Biblical terms, the authority on that would be Paul in the New Testament, **Romans 7** in particular (also **John 1:17** and **Romans 5:18**), which argues that, being sinners, the only obedience can be an imperfect obedience (a common conclusion being to thus never give up, but trying), arguing overall that we were never meant to fulfill the law, that only a guilty verdict comes through the ***Law of Moses***.

However, those concepts, and the idea of "perfect" obedience itself, approach the topic of Church Doctrine and denominational/traditional teachings, which is a question for the Christianity.SE site, not being purely Biblical Hermeneutics, so I won't go into that further here.

Answer (score 0):

Christ makes the best case for an eternal state of consciousness after death for his people in his use of Exodus 3:6 in Mat 22:32 where he says, "I am the God of Abraham, and the God of Isaac, and the God of Jacob? God is not the God of the dead, but of the living."-  Seemingly to express the point that Yhwh calls himself these men's God, thus equating them as living in some sense or perhaps in ration to time in a future state.
However, nowhere in the Torah it self speaks directly to a "heavenly" state as the more modern Christian concept speaks of it; rather we read time and again from Genesis 25:8 concerning Abraham to Deuteronomy 32:50 concerning Moses. This is a Torah concept expressing both the idea of  eminent death and the idea of life beyond the body as well.

The testimony of the fall in the Genesis account sets all of the future tone for the reward of eternal life as part of the Torah,  in the "guarding or keeping of the way of the tree of life" which Yhwh had at the beginning allowed the eating of which was seemingly the source in some sense of Adam's eternal life:

Genesis 3: 22  And the LORD God said, Behold, the man is become as one of us, to know good and evil: and now, lest he put forth his hand, and take also of the tree of life, and eat, and live for ever:

23  Therefore the LORD God sent him forth from the garden of Eden, to till the ground from whence he was taken.

24  So he drove out the man; and he placed at the east of the garden of Eden Cherubims, and a flaming sword which turned every way, to keep the way of the tree of life.